# Downloading a file from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to write a javascript code that downloads a certain file from S3 once click a button. Can you propose me something that can work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading a file from S3 is done through the [GetObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) method of the SDK.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Key: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  IfMatch: 'STRING_VALUE',
  IfModifiedSince: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  IfNoneMatch: 'STRING_VALUE',
  IfUnmodifiedSince: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  Range: 'STRING_VALUE',
  RequestPayer: 'requester',
  ResponseCacheControl: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentDisposition: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentEncoding: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentLanguage: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseContentType: 'STRING_VALUE',
  ResponseExpires: new Date || 'Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' || 123456789,
  SSECustomerAlgorithm: 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKey: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
  SSECustomerKeyMD5: 'STRING_VALUE',
  VersionId: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

More information about using the AWS SDK in javascript can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/)

Comment: using getObject method can download only one file? Is it possible that more than one file(object) match the the params?

Comment: GetObject will return one file as you specify the Key in the params. Key is unique. See [Object Keys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys) for more info on keys

Comment: I wrote it. It returns ONE file object in the console, but I want to start the file download from the browser. How can I do it?